# How to use Get-WmiObject's class Win32_Processor with multi processor machines

Tags: wmi, get-wmiobject

In a multi processor machine, what does get-wmiobject -class 'win32_processor' processorId return ?
The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor) state

> Remarks
> On a multiprocessor computer, one instance of the Win32_Processor class exists for each processor.

But where in the command/query you specify which processor to read from ? Does it default to the 1st ? How one queries the 2nd processor (how do you specify which instance of Win32_Processor to query) ?

Here is the output of `get-wmiobject -class 'win32_processor'`
[image]

Comment: Doesn't the command return a collection of instances, which can be iterated, as in the example script on that link? What command/code are you running? What is the result?

Comment: @underscore_d: it does not look so

Comment: So what is your system? What other CPUs does it have?